# retrieve data from firebase and set VC to match users preferences

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a viewController that is very similar to tinder. A user can swipe left or right depending on how many values are stored in firebase. Every value from firebase shows on the users VC no matter if it matches their preferences or not.  I wanted to allow users to have preferences (again, very similar to tinder.) and only values that fall within those limits to show on the viewController. The way I am fetching all of the values from firebase is

```
    func fetchPost() {
    
    topCardView = nil
    var previousCardView: CardView?
    Database.database().reference().child("Post").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        
            if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                
                let poster = Poster(dictionary: userDictionary as [String : AnyObject])
                let cardView = self.setupCardFromUser(poster: poster)
                self.cardViewModels.append(poster.toCardViewModel())
                
                if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
                    currentUser == poster.fromId {
                    cardView.removeFromSuperview()
                    } else if self.topCardView == nil {
                      self.topCardView = cardView
                    }
                
                previousCardView?.nextCardView = cardView
                previousCardView = cardView
                
        }
    
    }, withCancel: nil)
   
}
```

The code above, allows the user to see every single value from firebase. but the preferences I want to manipulate this is cost and skills.

is there a simple way for me to only show the values from firebase if they match the users preferences?

in firebase, the usersPreferences tree is set up as

```
users
|______ usersUID
|______ minSeekingCost
|______ maxSeekingCost
|______ skills1
```

and how the postings are set up look like

```
post
|____ usersUID
|____ category
|____ cost
```

I want the users to find postings that are within the min&maxSeekingCost, and match their skills. Say if a post matches one of their skills, and the price is not within their limits, then it is not fetched. Same for if post does not match and the price is in their limits.

would I have to fetch the users preferences inside of the fetchPost? or can I manipulate the fetchPost itself to have these called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for queries, which allow you to [order and filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

**But** Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In certain cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: Hey frank! Thanks for your answer! I am new to querying. I have posted a quick update to my question. So what you are saying is I wont be able to query the two items?

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database can only sort/filter on a single property. My linked answer shows how (in many cases) you can merge values into a single property, to order/filter on multiple values. If that doesn't work, it also shows other workarounds.

Comment: last quick question! Would I have to fetch the users info and the post info inside of the same func in order to match the post with the users preferences?? I am trying now and having issues hahaha

Comment: That seems to be a different problem, so I recommend opening a new question for that.